# Exchange 2003 - use a smarthost for all mail, even local domain, howto?

Tags: exchange-2003, mx-record

I have an exchange instance installed and working, but I do not want this machine to delivery email itself. To explain:-

Exchange server hosts domain foo.com. User A logs in to send a message to userB@foo.com Exchange looks up this user, and delivers it locally. This message never leaves this box. I need this message to pass through another system, where all mail for domain foo.com is handled and distributed/logged etc correctly.

How can I configure exchange to believe that it is *NOT* the MX for the domain on which it sits?

Comment: I used a combination of a .localdomain - and contact cards and aliases to ensure that mail got delivered to the correct mailboxes, and after that I was able to remove the temorary domains that I used for the transistion. I was able to keep it transparent to the end users, and job done. Thank you for the tips and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for a limited number of users, then this can accomplished with Custom Recipients (a.k.a. aliases). For "bulk" redirection to another server, then this can be accomplished through the SMTP connector - http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Configuring-SMTP-Connector.html. Ultimately, "swinging" the MX is the "better" route, if there is no other reasons for the emails to flow though the subject server.

Comment: I tried 'swinging' the MX records, but Exchange decides to just believe that it is the destination if the domain is configured as the primary in the recipient policy, even if DNS records being hosted on the same box explicitly say, "Hey, the email for domain foo.com gets delivered to realMX.foo.com not exchange.foo.com"

- But I did find a solution :) - I'm going to comment on my own question for that!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that Exchange journaling could resolve.  Journaling will send all of the mail to a mailbox or mailboxes.  Exchange 2003 does not allow for granular journal, as it can only be configured per database.

Microsoft Article
[Journaling with Exchange Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997525%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

Comment: I've got exchange journaling setup, but that is for my mail archive - But I did find a solution :) - I'm going to comment on my own question for that!

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this problem was simple. I picked up the phone, called the rest of Management, and said;

"If you want a miracle, pray, if you want the impossible, call Ethan Hunt, if you want me to build you a proper network, shut up and I'll tell you what is the "best" way to do it. After all, that's what you pay me for, right :)"

Then, I called my guys on the floor, and told them to tell everyone they will experience intermittent problems for the next four hours. This was at 9AM London time.

About 20 minutes ago (1.10PM), we finished, and everything is smoother than Angelina Jolie's inner thigh!

You know what the funny thing is? They are more pissed off about four hours intermittent downtime -- than 2 month overdue project?! *Go figure*

It's signed off and completed now, and I'm running a full backup across every computer, just to get a snapshot of our systems on *Friday 13th* just in case. Thanks for your time, and efforts, I think I like this site alot

Comment: Um, this wasn't an answer, just a silly gloat.

Comment: Not really a gloat my friend, (maybe a little). The point is, sometimes the answer is

*"Do it the right way, not the way someone else wants it, especially if they have no idea how it works"*

You wouldn't tell your doctor, how to fix your broken leg now, would you?

I'm the one who has to pick up the pieces when it goes off the rails - But, this will be a red herring for anyone searching google, etc, so I'll refrain from such pearls of wisdom... for now. :)

Comment: I added a comment up top explaining what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not. i a server is responsible for a specific domain, and an email originates internally, it dimply does not leave the server. Standard behavior.  There is no way to make it generally send a copy to an external source.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you my friend! Other servers will take a look at the DNS records, to find out who's in charge, Exchange just says, screw it! I'll deliver it!

Comment: Not all other servers will look at DNS. Note that "I am responsible for this domain" is a setting in Exchange. So, exchange knows - legally ok - without DNS lookup it is responsible for a domain BECAUSE THE ADMIN CONFIGURES IT LIKE THAT.

Comment: I was pretty sure that it comes like that by default. That's what MS support said, rather than "Because the ADMIN configures it like that" Either way, I've made a progress on this.